# Repl showing error: object async is not a member of package scala on import

Tags: scala

I am using scala 2.11.7 Repl (ubuntu) when trying to do this import I am getting :

```
scala> import scala.async.Async._ 
<console>:18: error: object async is not a member of package scala
       import scala.async.Async._
                    ^
```

how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

`scala-async` is not part of Scala standard library. You need to import the module in your project.

If you use sbt, you can add the following to your build file.

> libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" %
>   "0.9.5"

Check out this [PR](https://github.com/scala/async/pull/142) about the lack of information about this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to load the jar into classpath,

```
scala -classpath jarname.jar
```